# Subtract sum of column from a column in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am inserting First four column multiple times, with new `paidVal`  . Now I want to get `sid,snameVal, balance`

I have used a inner join on studenttbl and feetlb.

here I have tried.
But I am getting 3 row when I should get 2 only. In the table there is a field **cNameVal**, and as much different value i m entering I am getting that much row.

```
sql
SELECT studenttbl.sid,
       studenttbl.snameVal,
       studenttbl.sPhoneVal,
       coursefeeval - SUM(paidval) AS balance,
       CONVERT(varchar, studenttbl.sdateVal, 106) AS sdateVal
FROM feeTbl
     INNER JOIN studenttbl ON feeTbl.sid = studenttbl.sid
GROUP BY studenttbl.sid,
         studenttbl.snameVal,
         coursefeeval,
         sPhoneVal,
         sdateVal;
```

**feetbl**

```
 sid       snameVal cNameVal    courseFeeVal    paidVal 
    1001    Vivek     7            4000          1000   
    1001    Vivek     7            4000          1000   
    1002    Rahul     8            5000          1000   
    1002    Rahul     5            6000          5000
```

Comment: Please don't add screen shots, add the actual data in your question as text and use the provided tools to format it.

Comment: Okk Sure , Let me update it

Comment: Whitespace and line breaks are "magical" things. That make long unreadable lines of code suddenly readable.

Comment: Without your data we cannot see the problem ? Can you add some sample data and expected outcome please

Comment: To me it seems weird that you are including `coursefeeval` in the `GROUP BY`. If there are multiple courses with different fee values then it would make multiple rows, no? Don't you need to sum it too to get overall fees across all the courses?

Comment: It gives error, when not including `coursefeeval`

Comment: Yea, but single student could have multiple `coursefeeval`, right? Then you should use `SUM(coursefeeval)` instead of `coursefeeval` and remove it from `GROUP BY`. But I am not sure what exactly you want, so some sample data/desired output could help.

Comment: i have added sample data.

Comment: first two rows of feetbl is identical. Will it consider single or multiple

Comment: Multiple, bt got the solution, I used `sum(DISTINCT coursefeeval)` instead of `SUM(coursefeeval)`.

Comment: Is there are no risks that there are two similar `coursefeeval`  for the same student? This way they would only be counted once, you can join on a grouped subquery too, maybe that is what you need?

Comment: We really could use an example of what values you want to see.  The data doesn't really make sense, at least with why you want to subtract the sum of one column from another.  What does the data represent?  It looks like maybe there's multiple rows for a student in `feetbl`.  But what does `feetbl` represent?  A fee?  How much the student paid?  Both?  Can there be multiple fees for a student, or will there be one fee with multiple paidval?

Comment: For example the second student has two different `courseFeeVal`, that is why you are getting two rows for them.  Why does having one row with 5000 and one row with 6000 make sense here?  And why would the row with 5000 show -1000 for your calculated value (5000 minus total of paid which is 6000)?

Comment: Ya, u are right, So can u help me with that query please.

Comment: I am inserting First four column multiple times, with new `paidVal ` . Now I want to get `sid,snameVal, balance`

Comment: So what are your expected results here exactly?

Comment: I want to get `sid,snameVal, balance` here balance means `courseFeeVal  - SUM(paidVal)'

Comment: So `2000` for `Vivek` and `-1000` and `0` for `Rahul`?

Comment: balance of Vivek (4000 -(1000+1000)) =2000 and Rahul (5000+6000)-(1000+5000)=5000

Comment: That isn't what you say in teh comment above, @VivekRajSingh . but the logic there is flawed. Shouldn't, therefore, the value for `Vivek` be `(4000 + 4000) - (1000 + 1000) = 6000` . That looks like you're after `SUM(courseFeeVal) - SUM(paidVal)` in one case but `courseFeeVal - SUM(paidVal)` in the other.

Comment: As mentioned, provide expected results, explain the logic. This is still unclear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With no expected results, this is based on this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69286298/subtract-sum-of-column-from-a-column-in-sql#comment122463007_69286298):

> I want to get `sid,snameVal, balance` here balance means `courseFeeVal - SUM(paidVal)'`

Seems like you want a windowed `SUM`:

```sql
SELECT st.sid,
       st.snameVal,
       st.sPhoneVal,
       coursefeeval - SUM(paidval) OVER (PARTITION BY st.sid) AS balance, --2 of these columns need qualifying
       st.sdateVal AS sdateVal --leave dates as a date and time data time, don't convert to a string
FROM feeTbl fT
     INNER JOIN studenttbl st ON fT.sid = st.sid;
```